# Rails SSE doesn't work with Unicorn server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server, unicorn, server-sent-events

I want to use server-side events with rails. It works locally without any problem. But it does not trigger on production with unicorn.
Is it possible to use SSE with unicorn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a threaded web server such as Puma, as each connection requires a separate thread to keep the long running connection open.